# What is the format for TimeZone in Asana API for date fields?

Tags: asana

I'm looking at the "modified_at" field for a task. I see the following "2013-09-25**T**03:55:22.054**Z**"

What does the T & Z stand for? I suspect it stands for the timezone information but I'm not sure how I can use it.

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very standard format to represent combined date and time, known as ISO 8601. If you're parsing the string, the "T" separates the date and time. The Z indicates "zulu time", also known as UTC or Greenwich Mean Time (versus some other time zone).

You shouldn't have to parse the string yourself though - basically every popular programming language has the ability to take this string and turn it into a Date/Time representation appropriate to the language.

javascript:
`date = new Date("2013-09-25T03:55:22.054Z");`

ruby:
`date = DateTime.iso8601("2013-09-25T03:55:22.054Z");`

etc.